# Autobean returns an autobean after using as()

Tags: java, gwt, autobean

in my gwt project i am sending objects with the gwt channel api to the client and use Autobean to encode and decode those objects. everything works fine, i receive a valid json string on the client and can decode that json string to the AutoBean back again. only the autobean.as() does not return anything different than the autobean itself.

IContactDto and ContactDto just contain getters and setters. and this is the facbory i wrote

**AutoBeanFactory**

```
public interface DtoFactory extends AutoBeanFactory{
    AutoBean<IContactDto> contactDto(IContactDto contactDto);      
}
```

**Server-side code**

```
DtoFactory dtoFactory = AutoBeanFactorySource.create(DtoFactory.class);
AutoBean<IContactDto> iContactDto = dtoFactory.contactDto(contactDto);
String sJson = AutoBeanCodex.encode(autoBean).getPayload();
// sending this json to the client
```

**Client-side code**

this is the code i use for decoding the valid json string

```
// sJson string looks like {"id":"6473924464345088", "lastUpdate":"1475914369346", "fullName":"testName1","givenName":"testName2"}

DtoFactory factory = GWT.create(DtoFactory.class);
AutoBean<IContactDto> autoBean = AutoBeanCodex.decode(factory, IContactDto.class, sJson);  // debugger: IContactDtoAutoBean_1_g$             
IContactDto iDto = autoBean.as(); // debugger still shows IContactDtoAutoBean$1_1_g$
```

i can actually use the getters and setters of this object, but as soon as i try continue to work this those objects i get a problem with the type signature.

any ideas how i can get the object i encoded back again?

Comment: What do you mean by " i get a problem with the type signature"? What do you want to do that doesn't work. To me, if you "can actually use the getters and setters" then everything's working as intended.

Comment: this is the error i get when i try to pass the Autobean object to a method that excpects a IContactDto. It is simply impossible to cast the autobean to the original class. I can reconstruct the IContacDto object by taking the values of the autobean getter, but this is really annoying and not as i think it should work. the documentation tells that the as() method returns the original class, so i wonder why it doent.

Comment: Your expectations are wrong. I'll check the doc, but u can guarantee you that it's not supposed to work like you expect it to work.

Comment: From [the javadoc](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/web/bindery/autobean/shared/AutoBean.html#as%28%29): "Returns a proxy implementation of the T interface which will delegate to the underlying wrapped object, if any." And when deserialising, there's no underlying wrapped object (but even then, `as()` returns a proxy, not the wrapped object)

Comment: thanks, so i will have to switch back to gson for gwt if there is no way to get the original created object back:-( anyway, please write you last comment as answer so i can mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AutoBean#as()` returns a *“proxy implementation of the T interface which will delegate to the underlying wrapped object, if any.”* (source: [javadoc](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/web/bindery/autobean/shared/AutoBean.html#as())), it will never return the wrapped object itself.

Moreover, when deserializing from JSON, there's no wrapped object, a new autobean is created "from scratch" and then filled with JSON (it actually directly *wraps* a `Splittable` from the parsed JSON: super-lightweight, just a thin typesafe wrapper around a JS object –or a `org.json.JSONObject` when not in the browser.)